# share data between 2 different controller with shared service

Tags: json, angularjs, service, controller

Hallo i have 2 different controller and i want to share some data from the first to the second.

First Controller:
 `validationApp.controller('loginCtrl'['auth','resetpass','$scope',function(auth,resetpass,$scope) {
                $scope.login = function() {
                    auth.login($scope);
                };`

The auth service is:

```
validationApp.service('auth',function ($http,ipCookie,$rootScope,$state,localStorageService) {

    $rootScope.authorized = false;

// function to submit the form after all validation has occurred

        this.login = function ($scope) {

        var hash1 =CryptoJS.SHA256($scope.password)
        var rootElem = {};
        var loginRequest = {
            username: $scope.username,
            hash: hash1.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)

        };
        rootElem.loginRequest = loginRequest;
        var makejson = JSON.stringify(rootElem);

         $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: url+'/users/'+ $scope.username +'/login/',
            data: makejson,
            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        })


            .success(function (data,status){
                if (200 == status) {

                    if((data.loginResponse.roles[0] == "USER") && (data.loginResponse.roles[1] == "ADMIN")){
                        $rootScope.authorized = true;
                        $state.go('admin');
                    }
                    else {
                        $rootScope.authorized = true;
                        $state.go('user');
                    }

                }    

            })
            .error(function(data,status){
                if (400 == status) {
                    $rootScope.authorized = false;
                    $scope.dataValidationError = true;
                    $scope.message = data.error.message;
                }
                else if(401 == status){
                    $rootScope.authorized = false;
                    $scope.dataValidationError = true;
                    $scope.message = data.error.message;
                }
                else if(500 == status){
                    $rootScope.authorized = false;
                    $scope.dataValidationError = true;
                    $scope.message = data.error.message;
                }

            })

    }
```

data is the returned JSON from Backend.

I want to share some JSON data for example data.loginResponse.username in the second controller.

The second controller is:

```
validationApp.controller('Secondcontroller'['auth','$scope','$state',function(auth,$scope){}]);
```

It's for make welcome {{username}} after login.

Comment: And ... the ... question is ?

Comment: none, just do his work! dont ask questions!

Comment: The question is how can i share data for example data.loginResponse.username in the second controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share the data to another controller you could use $rootScope if you only need the username from the first controller like this:

Your first controller:

```
validationApp.controller('Firstcontroller', function(.....){
   $scope.login = function() {
                    var data = auth.login($scope);
                    $rootScope.username = data.loginResponse.username;
                };
});
```

Your second controller:

```
validationApp.controller('Secondcontroller', function(.....){
   You could access $rootScope.username inside here...  
});
```

Comment: Ty i have put $rootScope.username = data.loginResponse.username; in my auth service code and now i can have access in the second controller to $rootScope.username.